# Checking if "at least one file" exists in Ant

Tags: ant

I can use the following Ant syntax to check if there is exactly **one** file given its pattern or exact name (in fact, I don't know about any file system allowing two files with the same name to coexist)

```
    <condition property="dependenciesXmlOk">
        <resourcecount count="1">
            <fileset id="fs" dir="ci" includes="dependencies.xml" />
        </resourcecount>
    </condition>

    <fail message="dependencies.xml not found. Please configure CI server to deploy the dependencies.xml file as an artifact to ci/ folder within this project" unless="dependenciesXmlOk" />
```

However, I now want to add a new condition and related error message. The Ant build must break if no `*.jar` file exists in my target directory. Copy&paste and I get the same for `.zip` (yes, there must be as many zip and jar files, but at least one of both extensions)

How can I do that in Ant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same logic as you do for checking file unicity, using a [resourcecount](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) condition with a `when`attribute:

```
<condition property="jarexists">
    <and>
         <resourcecount when="greater" count="0">
             <fileset dir="${target.dir}">
                 <include name="**/*.jar"/>
             </fileset>
         </resourcecount>
         <resourcecount when="greater" count="0">
             <fileset dir="${target.dir}">
                 <include name="**/*.zip"/>
             </fileset>
         </resourcecount>
    </and>
</condition>
```

snippet code above sets `jarexists` to true if there are at least one jar file and one zip file (but not necessary the same count of both file types) in target directory...